# Get input stream from USB device for decoding DAB+

Tags: java, signal-processing

I need to implement a DAB+ player. Therefore i ordered a DVBT stick which can also retreive DAB and DAB+ signals.
My simplified approach looks like this:
Read input stream, split for audio and further information, pass the audio part to the audio library and process the further information for displaying in a GUI.
So my first question is: how do i get the input stream delivered by the device?
Can i simply create a new file object and call something like getInputStream()?
Second question: Is anyone familiar with DAB decoding? How do i split the input stream for audio and other information? How can i synchronize it? Which audio library should i use?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to look at the various versions of the Java COMM API.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow, as it is right now your question will more likely be considered as too broad by the community since it's asking answers to multiple question at once. Please have a look at the [ask] page aswell as the  [StackOverflow's Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand how the site works in general !